# Rackspace saving file in text formats

Tags: file, zend-framework2, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Using Zend framework 2 and saving files to cloud using "Zendservice-rackspace", here is my code for saving the file. The code is saving the file but in text format as when i go the link it show the text format, not the image or pdf format of the file

```
$fileName =  $fileName.'_'.date('Ymd-His').".".$fileExt;
        $fileData = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
        $rackspace = new Files($user,$key);
        if ($rackspace->authenticate()) {
            $rackspace->storeObject('Photos', $fileName, $fileData);
            if ($rackspace->isSuccessful()) {
                $cdnInfo = $rackspace->getInfoCdnContainer($module);
                $url = $cdnInfo['cdn_uri_ssl'] . '/' . $fileName;
                return $url;
            } else{
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'success'=>true,
                    'msg'=>'File uploading failed to server'));
                exit;
            }
```